# How can I make usbmon log file (*.mon)?

Tags: linux, usb

I'm trying to vusb-analyzer.

It requires *.mon log file.

How can I make usbmon log file (*.mon)?

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt

Answer (score 0):

The document you linked in your question is actually the answer, please see the sections 1-3.

In section 3, it says:

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/0u > /tmp/1.mon.out
```

This will create a text file `1.mon.out`. Its structure is also described in the same document.

Now, how do I know that this is the file to be opened by `vusb-analyzer`? From what I see, the website of this project doesn't make it clear what the `*.mon` file is.

However, you can see it in the source code:
https://github.com/scanlime/vusb-analyzer/blob/master/VUsbTools/Log.py#L498

It clearly states, that the program uses the syntax described in the document that you already know:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usbmon.txt

The name of your file doesn't really matter, but if you want it to end with `".mon"`, you could simply use:

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/0u > ~/somefile.mon
```

---

Two warnings:

1. The line with `cat` I posted here is just an example and in order to use it, you will need to follow the steps in the document (it won't work without enabling `usbmon` first)
2. `vusb-analyzer` hasn't been updated for years and I wasn't able to run it on my machine. Its website mentions Ubuntu 8.10 so I wouldn't be surprised if others had problems running it, too. (For example, in order to reproduce your problem, provide more help).